# Moving the generated coordinates with the object

Tags: node-editor, texture-coordinates

I used the generated coordinates to texture a text that I'm rotating, and I want the generated coordinates to rotate in the opposite direction so as to counteract the text's rotation. To make an example, I'd want what happens with the "position" socket in the "geometry" node, but with the generated coordinates' color palette. If that makes sense.
I tried using drivers to counteract it (as you can see in the provided image), with no luck.
Is there a way to "keep" the generated coordinates in place without going through a ton of baking?
[image: where i'm at right now]

Comment: Humor me, as this is only a guess. But what happens if you use the Camera output from your Texture Coordinate node instead of Generated?

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to keep the colours, not the coordinates, but that might lead me somewhere

Comment: Try Geometry -> Position with a Vector Math -> Add 0.5 on all axes and Vector Math -> Scale 0.5

Comment: Actually I guess the scale amount would be dependent on the size of your object.  Might have to eyeball it